# Hadoop Metric in Ganglia dfs.namenode.fileinfoops. what does it signify?

Tags: hadoop, ganglia

I am running a 3 Node Hadoop cluster and monitoring it using Ganglia, I am able to see all hadoop metric in Ganglia web portal.

I couldn't understand what it means by `dfs.namenode.fileinfoops` metric?

Answer (score 1):

To make it more readable, the metric name is:

`dfs.namenode.FileInfoOps`

Perhaps it is the metric to track the operations related to getting/reading file information.
FileInfoOps is one of the NameNode Activities as you may see in this [puppet-jmxtrans](https://github.com/wikimedia/puppet-jmxtrans) ReadMe :

```
{
    "obj"    => "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeActivity",
    "attr"   => ["FileInfoOps", "FilesCreated", "FilesDeleted"],
}
```